# Foreign Key references 2 separate tables

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables both with primary ids:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(   Id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CONSTRAINT t1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE TABLE Table2
(   Id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CONSTRAINT t2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (Id));
```

I have a third table which I am trying to setup a foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE Action
(   TableId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CONSTRAINT ac_pkey PRIMARY KEY (Id));
```

I need to add a foreign key that can reference either table1 or table2 depending on which one has value.  Is this possible or am I going to have to setup a parent table for tables 1 and 2?

Comment: A FK cannot reference two tables in Oracle. You could set up a parent table, or combine `Table1` and `Table2`. Which is best depends on your situation.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it was possible but just figured I'd check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for a foreign key to reference one table or the other.

- You could combine `table1` and `table2` with a `type` column and then have the combination of `id, type` be the primary key of the combined table and the foreign key in `Action`.
- You could create a new table that is a parent of both `table1` and `table2` as well as `Action`
- You could create two separate columns in `Action`, on that references `table1` and the other that references `table2` and then create a check constraint that ensures that only one of those is populated.

Which approach you prefer will come down to exactly what you're trying to model.